# X Users Earned That Badge Where Value Of X is Wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Whenever I click on a badge, the new page header says X number of users earned that badge, but X is not the number of users, rather it's the total number of times that certain badge was given. Isn't it wrong?

For instance, popular question page shows {as of now} 13955 users earned this badge when 13955 users are not being displayed.

Comment: Hint: "**Recently** awarded to:"

Comment: ZiG is right, it should say instead "this badge was awarded XXX times"

Comment: Feature-request version: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93991/incorrect-title-in-badge-page-for-badges-that-may-be-awarded-multiple-times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page isn't designed to show every single person who ever earned it. It's showing who it was RECENTLY awarded to, and yes it can and does show the same user multiple times if they are awarded multiples of the same badge in the same time frames.