# "17 Users earned this badge." Not really

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [X Users Earned That Badge Where Value Of X is Wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/x-users-earned-that-badge-where-value-of-x-is-wrong)

Just noticed the "[Notable Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question)" badge says there are 17 users who have earned it. The list of users follows:

1. **Jeff Atwood♦**
2. balpha
3. Chris Upchurch
4. **Jeff Atwood♦**
5. Justin Standard
6. aleemb
7. Joel Coehoorn♦
8. **Jeff Atwood♦**
9. **Jeff Atwood♦**
10. Justin Standard
11. TheTXI
12. Aamir
13. Bill the Lizard♦
14. **Jeff Atwood♦**
15. Joel Spolsky♦
16. **Jeff Atwood♦**
17. Andrija

The list speaks for itself. This clearly isn't "17 users," when a person's username apppears once per awarded-badge. Since Jeff has won this many times, his name appears many times. I think perhaps a similar format as the profile-page-badge-list would be better:

#### 11 Users have earned this badge.

1. 6 x Jeff Atwood♦
2. balpha
3. Chris Upchurch
4. 2 x Justin Standard
5. aleemb
6. Joel Coehoorn♦
7. TheTXI
8. Aamir
9. Bill the Lizard♦
10. Joel Spolsky♦
11. Andrija

As opposed to showing the same name over and over. Of course another option would be to change the title text from "17 Users have earned this badge" to "Badge awarded 17 times," or something equivalent.

Comment: That's rather **bold** of you to call Atwood out like that.

Comment: The dupe speaks for itself: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/x-users-earned-that-badge-where-value-of-x-is-wrong

Answer (score 12):

It's mistitled.  It says **"17 Users earned this badge"** when it really means **"This badge has been awarded 17 times"**.

The number at the beginning strikes me as a good thing, so I'd reword it like this:

**"17 times has this badge been awarded"**

Comment: ... although that final wording does get voiced by Yoda in my head...

Comment: Awarded 17 times, this has.

Comment: Learn Forth quickly, I will.

Answer (score 3):

If the wording were changed to *Badge Awarded 17 times:* with the list following as Jonathan presented it the first time, then nothing is lost, the list is preserved as is...and it's now 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

That would be fine, **but** then you couldn't see the order they were earned in.

Comment: Leave the order based on first-occurrence. Place Jeff in the list according to when he received his first badge.