# Incorrect title in badge page for badges that may be awarded multiple times

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, badges

Looking at some badge pages, the title reads:

> $num Users earned this badge. Recently awarded to:

But for badges that can be received multiple times this is incorrect, and should actually be:

> This badge was awarded $num times. Recently awarded to:

Because there are `$num` badges but less than `$num` **users** involved. This is of course a bit pedantic, but the real reason I've noticed this is that I'm interested in seeing the distribution of such badges. More specifically, what I would really like to see is something like the following:

> This badge was awarded $numawards times *to $numusers different users*. Recently awarded to:

Where the italicized text only appears for badges that may be received multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change to the badges page was deployed last week that takes care of the phrasing here.  This one took slightly over 6-8 weeks.