# Fix badge overview page to use proper grammar

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tag-badges, grammar

This may be a pet peeve of mine, but the current badge overview page for tags forms the page's heading without taking into account the number of users who earned the badge. This results in the following heading (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/204/htaccess)):

```
1 Users earned this badge. Recently awarded to:
```

Since we all know one isn't plural, the heading should read:

```
1 User earned this badge. Recently awarded to:
```

Can we get an `if` statement in the page to kill the `s` on `Users` when the number of users equals one? :)

**Edit:** As per the comments of kiamlaluno and GraceNote, there is more improvement here than just the plural, namely:

1. The capitalization on user,
2. The lack of a subject in the second sentence, and
3. The tense of the first sentence.

All things that can be improved upon to improve the site!

Comment: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105 ;)

Comment: :O I just saw that post on meta! Good thing it's almost three years old :)

Comment: Why would you stop with the plural when there are other things to fix? `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Because it's such an easy fix! Apparently nobody are agreeing with me that proper grammar are useful.

Comment: He probably meant that you're ignoring other aspects of proper grammar (The capitalization on user, the lack of a subject in the second sentence... etc.)

Comment: @nickb: You? Proper grammar? Did you proof-read that last comment of yours?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought he meant that the fix is so miniscule that it's irrelevant, which must be everyone else's opinion. Also @animuson, I hope you know that my previous comment was a joke. :)

Comment: @GraceNote That is correct. Add to that the tense used in the first sentence, which could probably be a present perfect: "1 user has earned this badge."

Comment: [There's a Stack Exchange site for those of us who talk English good](http://english.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: See also ["viewed 1 times"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20683/viewed-1-times)

Comment: Flagged for moderator to close; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694

Comment: @DragonLord That's over two years old.

Comment: Related: [Incorrect title in badge page for badges that may be awarded multiple times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93991)

Comment: @David Except that the bug exists even there. See below.

Answer (score 3):

Ironinically enough, despite @David’s comment that there  allegedly exists [a StackExchange site for users who talk English good](https://english.stackexchange.com/), the bug still exists there:

[image: badge grammar bug]

To be clear, it should ***not*** read:

> 1 Users earned this badge.

Instead, it should  read more like this, with one user, and in lowercase:

> 1 user earned this badge.

On a site where users are supposed to use good English, this bug and others like it just detract from the alleged professionalism of the site.  Even worse, the cognitive dissonance it sets up is far too much like a sign that reads:

[image: cognitive dissonance sign]

Answer (score 2):

Yay localization! We now support plurals without beating people up with a giant S!